# RTK query and response from server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, rtk-query

```
updateTagCurrentValue: builder.mutation<any, {path: string, body: updateTagCurrentValueBody}>({
    query: (args) => {
        const {path, body} = args
        return ({
            url: `/v2/tags/${path}/values/current`,
            method: 'PUT',
            body: body,
        })
    },
    transformResponse: (response) => {
        return response
    }
})
```

I am new in RTK, this mutation is working well, but I can not understand how to get a response from server? I see it in inspect network tab, I see my added data in the server, but the response comes null

```
const [updateTagCurrentValue, {error, isSuccess}] = useUpdateTagCurrentValueMutation()

const onSubmit: SubmitHandler = async (data) => {
    let body: updateTagCurrentValueBody = {
        value: {value: JSON.stringify(data)}
    }
    try {
        let response = await updateTagCurrentValue({path: 'test', body}).unwrap();
        console.log(response)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }
}
```

I searched for solutions, and some people said add `.unwrap()` at the end of the call, but it didn't help. `transformResponse` also changes nothing, `isSuccess` changes from false to true after the second submission...

Comment: Do you see any CORS warnings on your console? Maybe the server doesn't allow JavaScript to access responses?

Comment: no, on success response is {data: null}, on error(mistake in url) response is 
{
    "error": {
        "status": "PARSING_ERROR",
        "originalStatus": 405,
        "data": "The requested method PUT is not allowed for this URL.",
        "error": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', \"<!DOCTYPE \"... is not valid JSON"
    }
}

Comment: This is not about the server sending a response or not. This is about the question if JavaScript is allowed to read that response. Browsers prevent that e.g. if the request is made to a different domain. Then the server sends a response and you see it in the network tab, but to JS it looks "empty".
Please read up on CORS.